# How to put bigrams to list pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a row in my dataframe that looks like this:

```
     bigrams                     other1     other2
[(me, you), (stack, overflow)] .................
[(me, you)]                    .................
```

I am trying to get my top 10 bigrams into a list so I can use it for comparison reasons. I have tried copy and pasting my top10 bigrams into a list like so:

```
list = ['(me, you)',  .....]
```

This doesn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Define "top 10"? What criteria determines this? Most frequently occurring?

Comment: Yes top 10 most occurring across the dataframe.

Comment: Lot of upvotes here... is this _that_ good a question? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.chain` (to flatten the list of lists in the "bigrams" column) and then `pd.value_counts`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bigrams': [['(a, b)', '(c, d)'], ['(a, b)'], ['(a, b)', '(e, f)']]})
df
            bigrams
0  [(a, b), (c, d)]
1          [(a, b)]
2  [(a, b), (e, f)]

pd.__version__
# '0.24.1'
```

```
from itertools import chain

n = 2 # Find the top N
pd.value_counts(list(chain.from_iterable(df['bigrams']))).index[:n].tolist()
# ['(a, b)', '(e, f)']
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us do with `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

list(dict(Counter(df.bigrams.sum()).most_common(10)).keys())
```

As cold mentioned below , using `itertools.chain` replace `sum`

```
from itertools import chain
l=list(chain.from_iterable(df['bigrams']))
list(dict(Counter(l).most_common(10)).keys())
```

Comment: As an alt: `[k for k, _ in Counter(chain.from_iterable(df['bigrams'])).most_common(10)]`

Comment: Also, it may be shorter typing but I do not recommend using `sum` on columns of lists from a performance standpoint...